# Expression template implementation in Rust like in boost::yap

Tags: generics, rust, expression-templates

I am trying to teach myself Rust and as a challenging learning project I want to replicate the design pattern of the C++ expression template library [boost::yap](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/yap.html). I don't want a full fledged implementation, I just want a small demonstrator to find out if Rust's generics are powerful enough to make it happen and learn something along the way.

I have come up with an idea but am currently stuck. My question is twofold:

- Is there currently a principle barrier that makes expression templates **with the transform feature** *(see boost::yap, or my code below)* impossible in Rust?
- If no, how can I make it work?

Here is what I have come up with so far.

I have an enum `E` that represents all supported operations. In practice, it would take two generic parameters representing the left and right hand side expressions of any binary operation and would have variants called `Add`, `Mul`, `Sub` and so on. I would implement the traits `std::ops::{Add, Mul, Sub}` etc. for `E<U>`.

For demonstration purposes however, let's assume that we only have two variants, `Terminal` represents an expression wrapping a value, and `Neg` is the only supported unary operation as of now.

```rust
use std::ops::Neg;

enum E<U> {
    Terminal(U),
    Neg(U)
}

impl<U> Neg for E<U> {
    type Output = E<E<U>>;
    fn neg(self) -> Self::Output {
        E::Neg(self)
    }
}
```

Next, I implement a trait `Transform` that lets me traverse an expression via its subexpressions with a closure. The closure will stop the recursion once it returns `Some(_)`. This is what I have come up with *(code does not compile)*:

```rust
trait Transform<Arg = Self> {

    fn transform<R,F>(&self, _f: F) -> Option<R>
    where F: FnMut(&Arg) -> Option<R> 
    {
        None
    }
}

impl<U> Transform for E<U> 
where U : Transform<U> + Neg
{
    fn transform<R,F>(&self, mut f: F) -> Option<R>
    where F: FnMut(&Self) -> Option<R>
    {
        // CASE 1/3: Match! return f(self)
        if let Some(v) = f(self) { return Some(v); };

        match self {
            E::Terminal(_) => None, // CASE 2/3: We have reached a leaf-expression, no match!
            E::Neg(x) => {      // CASE 3/3: Recurse and apply operation to result
                x.transform(f).map(|y| -y) // <- error[E0277]: expected a `FnMut<(&U,)>` closure, found `F`
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the compiler error:

```
error[E0277]: expected a `FnMut<(&U,)>` closure, found `F`
  --> src/main.rs:36:29
   |
36 |                 x.transform(f).map(|y| -y) // <- error[E0277]: expected a `Fn<(&U,)>` closure, found `F`
   |                             ^ expected an `FnMut<(&U,)>` closure, found `F`
   |
help: consider further restricting this bound
   |
28 |     where F: FnMut(&Self) -> Option<R> + for<'r> std::ops::FnMut<(&'r U,)>
   |                                        +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

This is my **Issue 1/2:** I want to pass in a closure that can work on both `Self` and on `U` for `E<U>` (and thus accepts also `E<E<U>>` and `E<E<E<U>>>`...). Can this be done for generic types in Rust? Or if my approach is wrong, what's the right way of doing this? In C++ i would use SFINAE or `if constexpr`.

Here is a little test for the expression template library, to see how this can be used:

```rust
fn main() {
    //This is needed, because of the trait bound `U: Transform` for `Transform`
    //Seems like an unnecessary burden on the user...
    impl Transform for i32{}

    // An expression template 
    let y = E::Neg(E::Neg(E::Neg(E::Terminal(42))));

    // A transform that counts the number of nestings
    let mut count = 0;
    y.transform(|x| {
        match x {
            E::Neg(_) => {
                count+=1;
                None
            }
            _ => Some(()) // must return something. It doesn't matter what here.
        }
    });
    assert_eq!(count, 3);
    
    // a transform that replaces the terminal in y with E::Terminal(5)
    let expr = y.transform(|x| {
       match x {
           E::Terminal(_) => Some(E::Terminal(5)),
           _ => None
       } 
    }).unwrap();
    
    // a transform that evaluates the expression
    // (note: should be provided as method for E<U>)
    let result = expr.transform(|x| {
        match *x {
            E::Terminal(v) => Some(v),
            _ => None
        }
    }).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(result, -5);
}
```

My **Issue 2/2** is not a deal breaker, but I am wondering if there is some way that I can make the code work without this line:

```
impl Transform for u32{}
```

I think having to do this is a nuisance for the user of such a library. The problem is, that I have the trait bound `U: Transform` on the implementation of `Transform` for `E<U>`. I have the feeling the unstable specialization feature might help here, but it would be awesome if this could be done with stable Rust.

Here is the [rust playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c1af21e6d55d157528550829344bc964).

## Edit:

If anyone else stumbles over this, here is a [rust playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d7da9ea2459e4428173ebefa1824183f) that implements the solution of the accepted answer. It also cleans up some minor buggy stuff in the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) to me.

The solution [here](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/patterns/patterns/behavioural/visitor.html) looks similar to what you are trying to do.

The difference from your attempt is that U type is placed on heap in `Box<U>` (think of `unique_ptr<U>` in C++), which makes the whole E size fixed (independent of a concrete U).

In addition to make the compiler happy to unify the type of F and Transform such that it can work with both E and U at the same time, the trait argument of F probably needs to be boxed as well as `Box<dyn Transform>` (this is roughly analogous to marking `transform` as a virtual method in C++ to be able to call it via a "smart" pointer that knows how to find a particular impl in runtime). Having unpacked `x: U` using match, it should be possible to make a `Box::<dyn Transform>::new(x)` from it since `U : Transform`. With that F would accept it.

Without Box I think that the only other solution is to use macros, and generate methods for each type explicitly.

Comment: sweet!! I was about to give up on this, but boxing `U` did the trick, [see here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c1af21e6d55d157528550829344bc964).

Comment: nice. is it a correct link? it looks like the original code to me

Comment: oh, sorry. This is the correct one: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d7da9ea2459e4428173ebefa1824183f

So my second issue actually gets solved by this too, because I don't actually need the trait bound `U: Transform` if I make the `Transform` trait generic over `U`.